# How can i get result of a meteor async method in my client

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, meteor

I have to execute a python script on server. This script is taking time to answer but i need the response of my script in my client.

```
/* here is the server side */

async function myRequest(options) {
    await PythonShell.run('converter.py', options, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("in my request")
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    });
}

Meteor.methods({
    'findRealName': async function (id) {
        let options = {
            mode: 'text',
            pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python',
            pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
            scriptPath: '/Users/eliott/Desktop/influFinder/client/',
            args: ['-i', id]
        };
        var result = await myRequest(options)
        console.log("in find name")
        console.log(result)
        return result
    }
});

/* here is the client side */

Template.search.events({
    'click #searchButton': function() {
        var id = 2220626204
        var result = Meteor.call('findRealName', [id], (error, res) => {
            console.log("in client")
            console.log(res)
        })
        console.log("in client 2")
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```

Server side output : 
in find name
undefined
in my request
USERNAME

Client side output :
in client 2 
undefined
in client
undefined

In server i print the good result but in client it is always "undefined" no matter what i do.
I just want to get the result that i can print in my server side console log and store it in a client side variable

Comment: You will always get `undefined` for the data because it is an asynchronous function.  That means it is running off on it's own so you don't lock the main thread of a program.  To handle a situation like this, you'd need to have an `await` in your client to make sure you are waiting for the results to come back.  Checkout out some articles about `async/await` to see some examples about how this would work.

Comment: I've already tried that way : 

Template.search.events({
     'click #searchButton': async function() {
        var id = 2220626204
        var result = await Meteor.call('findRealName', [id])
        console.log(result)
    }
});
 
and i get the same result

Comment: Have you tried using the optional 3rd parameter in Meteor's `call` function to see if the results come back then?  I'm not a Meteor expert but none of the examples I've seen online use the `async` keyword to make asynchronous code calls.  https://blog.meteor.com/using-promises-and-async-await-in-meteor-8f6f4a04f998

Comment: Hey thanks to help me with that ! I've just reposted my problem at the current state. If u have enough time to take a look at it i would be so happy. I tried with and without async/await and i achieve the same result...

Comment: Have you tried using the same code base without using any `async` functions?  Just let the code run synchronously and see what happens with results then?

Comment: Thank you so much for your time Michael, my friend Titouan solved my issue. Thank u again !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try with Promises, like so :

```
async function myRequest(options) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        PythonShell.run('converter.py', options, function (err, result) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log("in my request")
            console.log(result);
            resolve(result);
        });
    });
}
```

Can't test now, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you so much my friend you solved my issue. #LOVEYOU